# Using remote netsh - not listing (or dumping) interfaces

Tags: windows-server-2003

So, this may be a misunderstanding on my part of how netsh is supposed to work. If I am logged onto server A (or apparently any other server), I can run `netsh interface ip dump` and get what I want (which is at heart, a list of all DNS servers for all interfaces for all machines in my domain.) See "Local" below.

If I do it from another (apparently, any other) machine in the domain via `netsh -r A interface ip dump`, it doesn't actually give me any of the interfaces or their info. (See "Remote" below.) Same thing happens in interactive mode, as well.

Thoughts? I've done some googling, with no description of this problem at all. I haven't found any machines that this works properly on.

Local:

```
# ----------------------------------
# Interface IP Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface ip

# Interface IP Configuration for "Team BE"
set address name="Team BE" source=static addr=xxxx mask=255.255.224.0
set address name="Team BE" gateway=xxxx  gwmetric=0
set dns name="Team BE" source=static addr=xxxx  register=PRIMARY
add dns name="Team BE" addr=xxxx index=2
set wins name="Team BE" source=static addr=none

popd
# End of interface IP configuration
```

Remote:

```
# ----------------------------------
# IPv4 Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface ipv4

reset
set global icmpredirects=enabled

popd
# End of IPv4 configuration
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer why it doesn't work rationally (it seems that what you noted extends to 2008R2 as well, and also fails if you do -r to the server you are currently on!) but I can offer a workaround suggestion:

```
psexec \\A netsh int ip dump
```

If you're playing with remote access to servers, you might as well just go straight to the big guns.

---- **UPDATED**

The best I can tell, `netsh int ip dump` runs a bunch of commands and then specially formats the output to make a runnable script. It looks to me as if dump tries to run every possible command and runs foul of unsupported remote issues and just fails. On some versions of netsh it also fails to run parts remotely and returns the LOCAL machine's config!

I'm thinking you'd be better off running the individual commands you want on each machine and interpreting the results that way. The remote dump seems to be universally broken no matter what OS I start from or access. Xp, 2003, 2008, Win 7. All misbehave one way or another when you try to use dump.

I suspect when you try it that way you'll run into the real problem... for me it seems to want to run Routing and Remote Access Service just to answer questions about the interfaces. And that service is disabled on most machines. This is not a helpful answer but its all I got.

Comment: That was what I started with, but our AV program snags psexec as suspect and causes the invoking machine's psexec process to just hang, meaning I can't loop through a list of machines and skip the ones that it won't run on. I may be able to get psexec on the whitelist, but our AV is a thicket of mess. Since netsh is *supposed* to work remotely, I'd like to make it do so.

Comment: Awesome edit, I just wish I could find some documentation that what you and I are seeing is the *correct* (or at least known) behavior.

Comment: Looks like RRAS is indeed required to do thing like "show ipaddress" remotely. Even enabling that on my remote machine doesn't give me "show dns" or several other options when using "netsh -r"